# assigning a post value to a variable or session var after reloading the same page

Tags: php, variables, post, assign

i have a php page that accept a posted value from previous page and this posted value is assigned to a variable but in the same page i have a button that reloads the page which causes the the posted value to be "null". im getting the un identified index notice. and also i have tried solving it with isset function its also not working. tried assigning it to a session variable and also im getting the same error! any ideas on how to solve this ??

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="products-wrapper">
    <h1>products</h1>
    <div class="products">
    <?php
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL

    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (isset ($_POST["shop_id"])) { $_SESSION["shop_id"] =  $_POST['shop_id'];}
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products2 where shop_id='".$_SESSION["shop_id"]."'");
    if ($results) { 

        //fetch results set as object and output HTML
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<div class="product">'; 
            echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
            echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
            echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
            echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo 'Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' | ';
            echo 'Qty <input type="text" name="product_qty" value="1" size="3" />';
            echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
            echo '</div></div>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you started session before by using `session_start()` at top?

Comment: yes the session already starts in the previous page

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add `@session_start();` on top of the page.

```
 if (isset ($_POST["shop_id"])) { $_SESSION["shop_id"] =  $_POST['shop_id'];}
```

Comment: tried it and still getting the same notice! Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in...

Comment: Add `@session_start();` on top of the page.

Comment: ughh Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in the previous page

Comment: Where  `shop_id` POST value came from?

Comment: from a page named shops_list.php that contain a form and sends the shop id value to the above code

Comment: what is the `print_r($_SESSION);` output?

Comment: Array ( [shop_id] => 4 ) BUT after clicking Add to cart button it throws Notice: Undefined variable:

Comment: Why cant you add hidden value and try to post `echo '<input type="hidden" name="shop_id" value="'.$_POST['shop_id'].'" />';`

Comment: Will try it. But why the session variable looses its value ?isnt it supposed to be stored unless i destroy the session ?

Comment: Yes you are right! You may check check where in your coding may be reinitialised or something.!

Comment: Yes the only initialisation of the session variable is on this page and its being checked if its initialised in the same line